# Error while deploying a Change Set: Could not find related list [AttachedContentNotes] for entity [Contact]

Tags: related-list, change-set

I am trying to deploy a Change Set to a different Org. I am getting the following error:

```
Could not find related list [AttachedContentNotes] for entity [Contact]
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Does the other org have the Enhanced Notes setting turned off?

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed. That was exactly the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by David Reed in the comments about, the Enhanced Notes was turned off. Once enabled the Change Set deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as I was trying to deploy to a scratch org. My dev hub account had Enhanced Notes turned on, but my scratch org did not. Enabling the Enhanced Notes in the scratch org is necessary before deploying to the scratch org.